# Create page options for theme?

Tags: themes

Is there any "default" possibility to create page options for theme? I found only some page builder like visual composser etc... but I need it only for page options like set social links or colors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the WP_Customizer API you can create you own options and settings. The WP_Customizer is simple to use, create the section, define the setting and the control. Then go to the customizer page and you can set values.

Answer (score 0):

Not a default option, but [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) is great for doing things such as that. I use it on every project.

Comment: Thank you, I know ACF, but I develop at the moment a free theme and I cannot give there ACF PRO files, this is the reason why I asked about a auto-solution.